# Custom image class rendering method

Tags: silverstripe

I wish to change img tag inside some Page template element to another tag. It's necessary to use parallax effect for each image on page (without specific class or created in CMS). Because Images cannot be styled, I decided to replace img tag with another. I can do this using JS, so poor browser won't be affected, but decided to ask could it be done by PHP and silverstripe?

In response to  Conny Nyman's text. There an example JS code.

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.Paralax'); // Obtain images to which should been paralax effect apply
for (i = 0; i < el.length; ++i) {
    // Create more elements, for example parent of div created bellow, so browser will properly calculates height - or use getComputedElementStyle from image element and apply result to nel
    var nel = document.createElement('div');
    nel.style.background = 'url("' + el[i].getAttribute('src') + '")';
    el[i].parentNode.insertBefore(nel, el[i]);
    el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]);  
}
```

Above code will do this, by using JS. I realize I need to not use JS, but add server support. Because Page was generated by many templates and I need allow to add paralax image from CMS, I need a way to add global template for all img tag, which checks only img have Paralax class.

Comment: Could you provide more code examples of what you're doing? Is there a reason why you can't modify the `.ss` template directly with your own custom logic? E.g.
`<% if $SomeFlag %> <img src="$Image.Link"/> <% else %> <some-other-tag attribute="value" /> <% end_if %> ...`  etc.

Comment: Post updated. I research this as my work. Additionally page wasn't uploaded yet, so I wrote only code snippet.

Comment: I done this task. Everything worked, but I must repeat this task in home. When I done, I will answer this topic.